# how to find this function complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I got log n but it's not log n it is log(log n) 
 but why?

```
int function(int n){
  return aux(n , 2)
}

int aux(int n, int x){
  while (n<x) {
    x *= x;
  }
  return x;  
}
```

what is the complexity of **function** ?

Comment: Infinite.  This algorithm will never terminate if `n` is less than 2.  The *code* on the other hand will overflow after 5 or 6 iterations depending on your architecture.

Comment: Actually, it's *O(1)* if `n>0`, because the number of operations needed to overflow `x` is independent of `n`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x < n`? This is pretty weird.

Comment: @user3386109 No it isn't.  Technically, only *algorithms* have big-O complexity, not actual *code* because all code exists and executes in a finite context where Big-O complexity has no meaning.  *Code* is *always* either `O(0)` or `O(infinite)`.

Comment: Or you could take a practical view that big-O indicates how the running time of an algorithm varies with the value of N. If you aren't interested in the practical application of theory, then I agree with you that theory has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the loop condition is supposed to be `n > x` so I'll be assuming it in this answer.

First, observe the values of `x`:

```
x1 = x0 * x0
   = 2 * 2
   = 2^2
x2 = x1 * x1 
   = x0 * x0 * x0 * x0
   = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
   = 2^4
x3 = x2 * x2
   = x1 * x1 * x1 * x1 
   = x0 * x0 * x0 * x0 * x0 * x0 * x0 * x0
   = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
   = 2^8
```

We see that the exponent is growing as `2^t` where `t` is the number of iterations in the loop so we can obtain the closed form equation for `x`:

```
x = 2^(2^t)
```

Then we can solve for the number of iterations `t`:

```
n > x
=> n > 2^(2^t)
=> log(n) > 2^t
=> log(log(n)) > t
```

as required.